# How to assign value from a model inside model list

Tags: c#

Check the code below. I have added List of `Model2` inside `Model1`. Now how can I add value of Model2 from Model1?

I already tried like bellow but this seems not correct syntax on c#. Anyone can help on it?

```
var pagesView = new List<PagesView>();

                pagesView.Add(new PagesView
                {
                    themeCollectionList = new List<ThemeCollectionList>(
                        new ThemeCollectionList
                        {
                            CollectionDate = DateTime.Now,
                        }
                        ),

                });
```

Model1

```
 public class PagesView
    {
        public int PageId { get; set; }
        public string PageName { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public string storeUrl { get; set; }
        public List<ThemeCollectionList> themeCollectionList { get; set; }

    }
```

Model2

```
 public class ThemeCollectionList
    {
        public int CollectionId { get; set; }
        public string ThemeName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CollectionDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `ThemeCollectionList` is a misleading class name since the item it represents isn't a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct syntax and more readable would be:

```
var pv = new PagesView()
{
  themeCollectionList = new List<ThemeCollectionList>()
  {
    new ThemeCollectionList(){ CollectionDate = DateTime.Now, }
  }
}

pagesView.Add(pv);
```

You get an error, because you are trying to pass parameters in a constructor, while you have not defined any constructor and you can only use default, parameterless constructor.

Also, you'd need to fix your classes names, as they contain `List`, where they aren't colleciton at all, thus they;re misleading, switch to `Theme` instead of `ThemeCollectionList`.